# Step function unable to trigger ECS task on fargate cluster, permission issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

I am creating and running a task on my ECS fargate cluster.

Task definition (with role) and fargate cluster is already created.

When I use run task step in step function, I am getting following error,

```json
{
  "Error": "ECS.AccessDeniedException",
  "Cause": "User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/StepFunctions-my-state-machine-role-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/my-app-dev-exec because no identity-based policy allows the iam:PassRole action (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx; Proxy: null)"
}
```

The role attached to the step function has the following policies (as per the documentation provided by AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/ecs-iam.html)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:RunTask"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:task-definition/*:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:StopTask",
                "ecs:DescribeTasks"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:task/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:PutTargets",
                "events:PutRule",
                "events:DescribeRule"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:rule/StepFunctionsGetEventsForECSTaskRule"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "states:DescribeStateMachine",
                "states:StartExecution",
                "states:ListExecutions",
                "states:UpdateStateMachine"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:stateMachine:my-state-machine"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

with following trusted entities

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone help with what additional permission I need to give to resolve the above permission issue? From the error, I am not able to figure out what additional permission is required.

If I attach `AmazonECS_FullAccess` (aws managed) policy to the role, job works perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your task will use an IAM Role, you need to specify the additional permission 'PassRole'.

The best practice is to restrict which roles can be passed. So is recommended to add a condition limiting to only allow to pass roles to ECS tasks.

Try adding this statement to your policy:

```
  {
        "Action": "iam:PassRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "iam:PassedToService": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I really need to Resource to be "*" ? If I know the role used by ECS task, can I use that resource ARN in `Resource` section and leave `Condition` to be blank ?

Comment: Sure, remove the condition and specificy the role arn. It is more restrictive than the policy I put

Comment: Yes, this works. I have confusion here.  If I use `"*"` on `Resource`. Exactly which role will be passed to service `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`? How will step function know which role to use?

Comment: Also, instead of using pass role, why can't I add `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` to trusted providers, in that case ecs can assume the role defined above and run the task instead of passing this role. But it doesn't work. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Exactly which role will be passed to service ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com ?

Got the answer, it will be `task role` and `execution role` here.

Answer (score 2):

I know there's already an accepted answer but I'll add this one for completeness with a complete Clouformation template. I had the same problem and the current answer partially answered my question, because I wanted to avoid opening up the IAM ALLOW rule to ALL (*) resources. And it wasn't clear which ECS IAM roles to include (the answer is in the comments: the task role and task execution role).

Here is an example of a scheduled task that triggers once a week, calls a lambda function which will invoke an ECS update-service (my ECS Fargate service is defined so that it runs X nodes, and is allowed to go up to 2X nodes, that way ECS will stand up the new nodes, and destroy the old ones once the new ones are deemed healthy = zero downtime). In the code below, replace all occurrences of MY with YOUR cluster/service/IAMrole names (the two ECS roles need to be created separately, and should already exist if you have ECS tasks already running because ECS fargate uses those roles to start and run your ECS task/container):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Weekly roll (ecs update-service) new servers to take care of slow memory leaks (incurs no outage)

Resources:
  ECSLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: lambda-update-ecs-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'ecs-lambda-policy'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ecs:UpdateService'
                  - 'ecs:DescribeServices'
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:service/MY-ecs-cluster/MY-ecs-service'
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "iam:PassRole"
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/MY-ecs-task-role'
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/MY-ecs-task-execution-role'


  ECSLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Lambda function which rotates all MY ECS Service tasks
      FunctionName: !Sub 'weekly-restart'
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: !GetAtt ECSLambdaRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |         
          import boto3

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              ecs_client  = boto3.client('ecs')

              cluster_name = 'MY-ecs-cluster'
              service_name = 'MY-ecs-service'

              # get the current task definition for the service
              current_task_definition = ecs_client.describe_services(
                  cluster=cluster_name,
                  services=[service_name]
              )['services'][0]['taskDefinition']

              response = ecs_client.update_service(
                  cluster=cluster_name,
                  service=service_name,
                  taskDefinition=current_task_definition,
                  forceNewDeployment=True
              )
              print(response)


  # Create an EventBridge rule to rotate ECS service tasks every week
  ECSLambdaSchedule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: MY-Scheduled-Rule
      Description: Scheduled ECS Service task rotation to clear up memory leaks
      ScheduleExpression: 'rate(7 days)'
      Targets:
        - Id: !Sub 'weekly-restart-target'
          Arn: !GetAtt ECSLambdaFunction.Arn

Outputs:
  ECSLambdaRoleArn:
    Description: ARN of the IAM role created for the ECS Lambda function
    Value: !GetAtt ECSLambdaRole.Arn
  ECSLambdaFunctionArn:
    Description: ARN of the ECS Lambda function
    Value: !GetAtt ECSLambdaFunction.Arn
  ECSLambdaScheduleArn:
    Description: ARN of the CloudWatch Events schedule created for the ECS Lambda function
    Value: !GetAtt ECSLambdaSchedule.Arn
```